# zsh の履歴検索で、 emacs でいう helm (aka anything) ありますか

Tags: zsh

emacs でコマンドをヒストリから実行する際には、 helm (aka anything) が便利です。これ相当の機能ないし拡張スクリプトは、 zsh にあるでしょうか

具体的にやりたいことは:

- 履歴検索を開始すると、履歴一覧が表示される
- 履歴一覧は、文字入力でインクリメンタルサーチができてそれによって絞られていく

  - できれば、入力はスペースで区切られた複数の OR 条件として検索してほしい
- 随時、 C-n, C-p などで一覧の項目を選択可能、 RET でその項目に確定

今の手元の zsh は、履歴検索時 (`C-r`) には、 bash のそれと同じ挙動をしていて、若干不便なため質問しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私は[peco](https://github.com/peco/peco)とシェル関数を組み合わせて使っています。pecoは単一バイナリで動くので、ダウンロードして実行ファイルを`~/bin`あたりに置くだけで動きます。

Answer (score 1):

@emasaka さんのアドバイスを参考に、調査などを行った結果、

peco を PATH に通し、以下を `.zshrc` に記述すると実現できました。

```
function peco-history-selection() {
    BUFFER=$(
        history -n 1 |
            awk '{printf ("%d %s\n",NR,$0)}'|
            sort -k1,1 -r -n |
            sed 's/^[^ ]* //' |
            peco )
    CURSOR=${#BUFFER}
    zle reset-prompt
}

if type peco > /dev/null
then
    zle -N peco-history-selection
    bindkey '^R' peco-history-selection
fi
```